# acf on wordpress problem with Field Googlemap

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress with acfpro. I use it the options page for to create option page header and footer, next I declare custom field map on option page footer and paste code in footer.php. 
when I do it this, i have some pages where acf map not working and other pages is good!
wordpress 5.2, acfpro 5.7.13

```php
 <div class="left">
        <div class="zto-containMap">
            <?php
            $location = get_field('map');
            $long = $location['lng'];
            $lat = $location['lat'];
            if( !empty($location) ):
                ?>
                <div class="acf-map">
                    <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $lat; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $long; ?>"></div>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="acf-map">
                    not working
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't have a error message, and acf map is broken on 3 page on my site and the other pages are working nice width acf map

Comment: Hi @rhum, if you found my answer helpful please mark it as the accepted answer. If you have any questions please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the field value for an option, you have to declare the `option` scope in your second paramter of `get_field($field, $scope)`. If no `$scope` is passed in the `get_field()` function it will automatically use the `ID` value of `get_post()`.

This is what you're after:

```
$location = get_field('map', 'option');
```

[Here's the docs on getting the value of an Option field in ACF.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/)

While this is a little out of the scope of your question, [these docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/) explain a little further about how the `$scope` variable can be used in the second parameter.

Comment: @rhum Would you mind accepting this as the answer? It only takes a few mintues, here's some info on how to do it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235